# Camel-Blueprint Unable to convert value org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean to type org.hibernate.SessionFactory

Tags: camel-blueprint

I am using camel-blueprint and facing issues with hibernate component.
This example works fine in Spring but not in blueprint JBoss Fuse 6.3 V

The provided example is in spring and works fine but any example in blueprint will be helpful
http://camel.apache.org/hibernate-example.html

**Error:**
org.osgi.service.blueprint.container.ComponentDefinitionException: Error setting property: PropertyDescriptor Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Unable to convert value org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean@46797063 to type org.hibernate.SessionFactory
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.AggregateConverter.convert(AggregateConverter.java:184)

```
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 https://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd                            http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/camel-blueprint.xsd">
    <bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close" id="dataSource">
        <property name="url"
            value="jdbc:sqlserver://x:1433;DatabaseName=x" />
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />
        <property name="username" value="" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
        <property name="removeAbandoned" value="true" />
        <property name="initialSize" value="20" />
        <property name="maxActive" value="30" />
    </bean>
    <bean class="com.x.dto.ReferenceTable" id="refBean" />
    <!-- <bean class="com.x.dao.ReferenceDAOImpl" id="MyBean">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mysessionFactory" />
    </bean> -->

    <!-- setup the Camel hibernate component -->
    <bean class="org.apacheextras.camel.component.hibernate.HibernateComponent"
        id="hibernate">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mysessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean"
        id="mysessionFactory">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <!-- here we define the hibernate mapping files we use -->
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>com.x.dto</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.x.dto.ReferenceTable</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <!-- and here we have additional hibernate options -->
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <camelContext id="_context1"
        xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
        <route id="_route1">
            <from id="from" uri="hibernate://com.x.dto.ReferenceTable?consumer.query=select x.data from com.x.dto.ReferenceTable x where x.id='id3'"/>
          <!--   <bean id="_bean1" method="save(com.x.dto.ReferenceTable)" ref="MyBean"/>
            <bean id="_bean2" method="getByID('id2')" ref="MyBean"/>
            <convertBodyTo id="_convertBodyTo1" type="com.x.dto.ReferenceTable"/> -->
            <to id="_to1" uri="log: ${body}"/>
        </route>
    </camelContext>
</blueprint>
```

Pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-blueprint</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>bundle</packaging>
    <name>Camel Blueprint Quickstart</name>
    <description>Empty Camel Blueprint Example</description>
    <licenses>
        <license>
            <name>Apache License, Version 2.0</name>
            <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html</url>
            <distribution>repo</distribution>
        </license>
    </licenses>
    <properties>
        <camel.version>2.17.0.redhat-630187</camel.version>
        <version.maven-bundle-plugin>3.2.0</version.maven-bundle-plugin>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <jboss.fuse.bom.version>6.3.0.redhat-187</jboss.fuse.bom.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.fuse.bom</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-fuse-parent</artifactId>
                <version>${jboss.fuse.bom.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-blueprint</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-test-blueprint</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.0.jre8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache-extras.camel-extra</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-hibernate</artifactId>
        <version>2.15.0</version>
    </dependency>

     <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <id>fuse-public-repository</id>
            <name>FuseSource Community Release Repository</name>
            <url>https://repo.fusesource.com/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <id>red-hat-ga-repository</id>
            <name>Red Hat GA Repository</name>
            <url>https://maven.repository.redhat.com/ga</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <id>fuse-public-repository</id>
            <name>FuseSource Community Release Repository</name>
            <url>https://repo.fusesource.com/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <id>red-hat-ga-repository</id>
            <name>Red Hat GA Repository</name>
            <url>https://maven.repository.redhat.com/ga</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
    <build>
        <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${version.maven-bundle-plugin}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <instructions>
                        <Bundle-SymbolicName>keyvalue</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                        <Bundle-Name>Empty Camel Blueprint Example [keyvalue]</Bundle-Name>
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
                <artifactId>camel-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${camel.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <useBlueprint>true</useBlueprint>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 5):

Remember one thing. `org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean` is Spring's *factory bean* which, when used as `<bean>` gives you a kind of indirection - instead of using the class as bean directly, `getObject()` is called and the returned object is your `<bean>`.

Another thing is that Spring automatically calls `afterPropertiesSet()` for all beans (or factory beans) that implement `InitializingBean`.

So instead of:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean"
        id="mysessionFactory">
```

use:

```
<bean id="mysessionFactory" factory-ref="mysessionFactoryFactory"
      factory-method="getObject" />

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean"
        id="mysessionFactoryFactory" init-method="afterPropertiesSet">
...
```

Comment: First of all Thanks for the response. This is something new that I have learned. After the above changes I am getting expection                                            org.osgi.service.blueprint.container.ComponentDefinitionException: Unable to instantiate componentsCaused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.getInitMethod(BeanRecipe.java:619)

Comment: Excuse me - I was writing from top of my head - `init-method` should be added to bean with id="mysessionFactoryFactory", not to bean with id="mysessionFactory", because it should be called on `hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean` itself instead of on the return object of the factory (I hope it sounds clear ;)